# Dynamic Menu Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to hide all list elements, but only show one at a certain time depending on the direction or button pressed by the nav bar.

I've tried this:

```
$('ul li').hide().first().show();
```

which shows me the first element in the list.

But now I need to take control of the list with navigation which I don't know how to do.

Basically, I need a menu that has more or less this layout:

< - prev           LINK1            next - >
So basically, id have a unordered list, so the html would be like this

```
<ul>
    <li>LINK1</li>
    <li>LINK2</li>
    <li>LINK3</li>
</ul>
```

So, I need to only display one at a time, and once the next or previous buttons are pressed it would "loop through" the list if it's at the end or start.any plugin available to apply on it.

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
$(els).hide().end().first().show();
```